# ABAP Using Method As a Parameter

Tags: abap

I want to use the return value of methods directly.
For example in C++, we can use:

```
//Some codes
cout << obj1.get_foo() << endl;
int a = obj2->get_value() + 100 + obj2->get_value();
```

or

```
//...
obj1->set_color("BLUE");
cout << "Color is:" << obj1->get_color();
printf("Color is: %s", obj1->get_color()); // C Version
```

When I do this in ABAP like:

```
OBJ1->SET_COLOR( 'BLUE' ). "That's OK.

WRITE:/ 'Color is:', OBJ1->GET_COLOR( ). "Error!
```

And I expected this output:

```
Color is: BLUE
```

---

Edit: I used Parameter word in Title **not as ABAP Keyword**, but as function arguments.

Comment: Your question is not clear: you want to use the method RESULT, not pass the method itself, right?

Comment: What is the signature of GET_COLOR? What SAP_BASIS release are you using?

Comment: Get_color returns COLOR attribute. Its type is NAME. Sap 740, R/3

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @Enes We're using SAP ECC 6.0 and SAP GUI 7.3 and we can't make that kind of operation. We must create a variable to store that value there before use it in another operation. Can you provide more details of your SAP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is.

```
* before 740
OBJ1->SET_COLOR( 'BLUE' ).
DATA COLOR TYPE NAME.
COLOR = OBJ1->GET_COLOR( ).
WRITE:/ 'Color is:', COLOR.
```

or

```
* since 740
OBJ1->SET_COLOR( 'BLUE' ).
DATA(COLOR) = OBJ1->GET_COLOR( ).
WRITE:/ 'Color is:', COLOR.
```

Best regards,
Tapio

Comment: Thanks, i understood how to do it. So, my way isn't possible in ABAP.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution:

```
DATA : STRING TYPE STRING.


CONCATENATE 'Color is:' OBJ1->GET_COLOR( ) INTO STRING SEPARATED BY ' '.

WRITE :/ STRING .
```

if you have a multilingual application, with this method, you can get the right language for 'Color is:' at the same time.